# Android - Cursor is deprecated

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sqlite

working on a android app to develop my skills i am trying to delete all data on sqlite and and listview and then i requery the cursor to reflect the changes but i keep on getting `c.requery();` Cursor is deprecated

i do this:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.removeBtn:

            dm.deleteAll();
           c.requery();//<<this is deprecated 

            break;
        }
```

what do i need to put instead any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The "new" way is to just instantiate a whole new cursor.

instead of `c.requery();`

you would do

```
c = query(uri, ...);
```

Comment: what do i need to put where the dots are?

Comment: Put the same parameters you used to create the cursor originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the answer here: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery%28%29)