# DBHelper.getReadableDatabase().query() parameters

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I was given code to a pre-existing project and I noticed the previous programmer used:

```
DatabaseManager.getInstance(this).cursor.requery();
Cursor cursor = DatabaseManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).cursor;
```

I understand that `cursor.requery()` has been deprecated and a new cursor should be requested instead. So, I'm changing it to:

```
Cursor cursor = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase().query();
```

This is where I am confused. I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249450/android-cursor-is-deprecated) that the parameters that go in `query()` should be the same ones used when making a new cursor, but the previous programmer pulled the cursor from `DatabaseManager`, so in this case how can I tell what parameters should be passed in?

**Edit**
I know these are some of the parameters that can be passed in:
String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy

I just don't know how to determine the values. I've seen other people just pass in null for most of them, but they always have a table value. How do I know what table to pass in from the code that was given me?

Comment: you need to know the parameters in query method ???

Comment: @mohammedmomn I know the parameter fields, but I'm not sure how to tell what values to pass in from the code that was given to me. For example, I know I can pass in a table name, but where can I find that? From the question I linked to, it sounded like they got it from the Cursor? If so, would the table I should pass in be "MainActivity"?

Comment: if you need to know the content provider fields and tables name in mainfest.xml you will find provider section  with class name which you will find  all database details in it

Comment: @mohammedmomn Thank you! I didn't find it in the manifest, but it led me to a file that did have the information.